# StreamWriter Not working in C#

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

This piece of code worked perfectly in VS 2010. Now that I have VS 2013 it no longer writes to the file. It doesn't error or anything. (I get an alert in Notepad++ stating that the file has been updated, but there is nothing written.)

It all looks fine to me. Any Ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String line;
            try
            {
                //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Temp1\\test1.txt");
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Temp2\\test2.txt");

                //Read the first line of text
                line = sr.ReadLine();

                //Continue to read until you reach end of file
                while (line != null)
                {
                    //write the line to console window
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    int myVal = 3;
                    for (int i = 0; i < myVal; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                    //Write to the other file
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                    //Read the next line
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                }

                //close the file
                sr.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you looking in the right directory? have you opened the file as a sanity check?

Comment: Try explicitly flush as well.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you call sw.Close();  If you do that, the write will be flushed and the file closed.  Also, you should really look at wrapping the StreamReader and StreamWriter in using blocks - they both implement IDisposable, and will close automatically when you leave the using block

Comment: Additionally, it's a good idea to explicitly close your streams.  You're closing your stream reader, but not the writer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `Flush()` the StreamWriter after write.

By default StreamWriter is buffered that means it won't output until it receives a Flush() or Close() call.

Also you can also try to close it like this:

```
sw.Close();  //or tw.Flush();
```

You can also have a look at [StreamWriter.AutoFlush Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the StreamWriter will flush
>   its buffer to the underlying stream after every call to
>   StreamWriter.Write.

The other option which is now a days very popular and recommended is to use the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) which takes care of it.

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of
>   IDisposable objects.

Example:

```
using(var sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Temp1\\test1.txt"))
using(var sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Temp2\\test2.txt"))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Or event better, close it

Comment: You should use the "using" statement on the StreamReader and the StreamWriter.

Comment: @tdbeckett:- Yes thats the standard and the recommended way! Thanks for pointing that!

Answer (score 7):

You need to close StreamWriter. Like this:

```
using(var sr = new StreamReader("..."))
using(var sw = new StreamWriter("..."))
{
   ...
}
```

This will close streams even if exception is thrown.

Comment: +1 for best "Best Practices".  All IDisposable objects should (almost always) be paired with a using statement.

Comment: Yes, using statements should be used - no need to explicitly call Flush/Close, so much neater.

Comment: Also that loop can be cleaned up by combining the readline and the comparison
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //write the line to console window
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    int myVal = 3;
                    for (int i = 0; i < myVal; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                    //Write to the other file
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }